# Parsing a xml tree into a string list

Tags: python, xml, tree

I am trying to trying to parse my element xml tree into a list but the issue i'm having is arranging my tree into a proper string list format. How would I change it into a format like the example string list below?

```
with open('test.xml') as f:   #Used to call etree
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)
for root in tree.iter():
    print(root.attrib.get('name', root.attrib))
```

Output:

```
{}
{'response': '', 'action': 'Stay'}
{'response': 'Pause Menu', 'action': ''}
{'response': 'Sit', 'action': ''}
{'response': '', 'action': 'Enemy Rushing User'}
{'response': 'Dodge Left', 'action': ''}
{'response': 'Dodge Right', 'action': ''}
{'response': '', 'action': 'Move'}
{'response': '', 'action': 'Reverse'}
{'response': 'Back Left', 'action': ''}
{'response': 'Back Straight', 'action': ''}
{'response': 'Back Middle', 'behavior': ''}
{'response': '', 'action': 'Forward'}
{'response': 'Forward Left', 'action': ''}
{'response': 'Forward Straight', 'action': ''}
{'response': 'Forward Right', 'action': ''}
```

The sample string list i'm trying to make the element tree into:

```
List1 = {'A':['B','D','C'],'B':[],'C':[],'D':['E'],'E':[]}
```

If I were to print that list, It would be in this string list format

XML tree:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <node action="Stay" response="">
        <node action="" response="Pause Menu"/>
        <node action="" response="Sit"/>
    </node>
    <node action="Enemy Rushing User" response="">
        <node action="" response="Dodge Left"/>
        <node action="" response="Dodge Right"/>
    </node>
    <node action="Move" response="">
        <node action="Reverse" response="">
            <node action="" response="Back Left"/>
            <node action="" response="Back Straight"/>
            <node behavior="" response="Back Middle"/>
        </node>
        <node action="Forward" response="">
            <node action="" response="Forward Left"/>
            <node action="" response="Forward Straight"/>
            <node action="" response="Forward Right"/>
        </node>
    </node>
```

Comment: You should get the root element tree.getroot() and iterate over the children recursively, since the iter() method goes thru all elements and you don't really now which child belong to which parent. And to keep things in the same order as in the xml for final result you should use a list or if you insist in having a dictonary use OrderedDict